# Confusion between would and must

Tags: modal-verbs

Why would is used in the following sentences instead of using must?

> 1. "That would be Ram calling. I will answer it."
>      (does it shows possiility or certanity? if it shows certainity, why would used here instead of using must? is the first sentence in past tense?)
> 2. "The guy on the phone had a southern accent." "That would be Tom".
>      (does it shows possiility or certanity? if it shows certainity, why would used here instead of using must? is the second sentence in past tense?)
> 3. We saw a police helicopter overhead yesterday Morning. Really? They would have been looking for those bank robbers.
>      (does it shows possiility or certanity? if it shows certainity, why would used here instead of using must ? is the second sentence in past tense?)

I have a hard time understanding the uses of 'would' in the sentences above, why "must" hasn't been used there? I would be greatfull if anyone could anser me sentences,thanks.

Note : unlike previous question which was about would, This question is different because here i have confusion between 'must' and 'would'

Comment: "must" could be used there, but there's nothing wrong with "would," either.

Comment: My question is why *would* is used there instead of using *must*?

Comment: I have no idea why. When there's more than one way to say something, you have to pick one.

Answer (score 1):

Would and must in this usage show difference in the strength of the logical reasoning.

> "That would be Ram calling. I will answer it."
>   (does it shows possibility or certainty? if it shows certainty, why would used here instead of using must?)

"Would" implies high probability.  This is not the same as certainty.
"Must" is used when there are no other conclusions that can be drawn from the premise.  If someone else may be calling, no matter how slight a chance, use "would".

Answer (score 0):

It's idiomatic. Modal verbs usually have strange alternative uses in most languages.

It's something you'll just have to learn.

EDIT: and the two sentences are interchangeable here.